# Deleted row from database still shows up in select statement right after delete

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have a WPF project written in C# that uses a sqlite database.

I try to delete one of my rows from a table and then after I return to the method that called that delete I then try to get all rows in that table and it returns the deleted row.

The strange thing is if I try to return all of the rows right after I do the delete but not return then it returns all rows minus the one I deleted,
but if I return to the calling method and then try to return all rows the deleted row shows up.

```
        private void RemoveTagScannersButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TagScanner tagScanner = (TagScanner)dgTagScanners.SelectedItem;
            ScannerDAO scannerDAO = new ScannerDAO();
            scannerDAO.DeleteScanner(tagScanner.Id);
            //here is where I load the scanners after deleting the scanner row in the database
            //and the deleted scanner row is returned dispite the fact that I just deleted it.
            LoadScannerInformation();
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }          
    }


        internal bool DeleteScanner(int id)
    {
        int result = -1;
        string connectionString = "Data Source=" + LocationManager.DatabaseLocation  + "\\LapCounter.sqlite";
        lock (ConnectionManager.instanceLock)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = ConnectionManager.CreateConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tagscanners WHERE id=@id";
                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    try
                    {
                        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (result == 0)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SQLiteException e)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        /*I added next line because when I return to the calling method and call 
          GetTagScannersForRace(1) the returned rows include the deleted row, but if I call it 
          right below before I return to the calling method the returned rows does not contain
          the deleted row
         */
        //List<TagScanner>  scanners = GetTagScannersForRace(1);        
        return true;
    }



        private void LoadScannerInformation()
    {
        List<TagScanner> scanners = getTagScanners();
        dgTagScanners.ItemsSource = scanners;
    }




        List<TagScanner> getTagScanners()
    {
        if(_tagScanners.Count == 0)
        {
            ScannerDAO scannerDAO = new ScannerDAO();
            _tagScanners = scannerDAO.GetTagScannersForRace(_raceId);
        }
        return _tagScanners;
    }


        public List<TagScanner> GetTagScannersForRace(int raceId)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=" + LocationManager.DatabaseLocation + "\\LapCounter.sqlite";
        List<TagScanner> scanners = new List<TagScanner>();
        try
        {
            lock (ConnectionManager.instanceLock)
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = ConnectionManager.CreateConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tagscanners " +
                        "WHERE raceid=@raceid";
                        cmd.Prepare();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raceid", raceId);

                        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                TagScanner currentScanner = new TagScanner();
                                currentScanner.Id = Int32.Parse(reader["id"].ToString());
                                currentScanner.TagScannerIp = reader["tagscannerip"].ToString();
                                scanners.Add(currentScanner);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            return scanners;
        }
        return scanners;
    }
```

Can anyone explain why right after I delete the row a select of all rows returns all rows minus the deleted row, 
but if I return to the calling method and select all rows it returns all rows including the deleted row.

Comment: You don't show the code that selects it, but one of: your delete - deleted nothing, or the wrong thing / your select and delete are talking to different databases (or accounts) / your database is broken

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for responding! I just added the method that selects all the scanners  . I also verified that the select and delete are pointing at the same database.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Marc Gravell pointed me in the right direction.
I deleted the database and once deleted my code creates a new one for the running app.
Now my deletes actually do show up in the table, so I am assuming it was a broken or corrupted database.  I've never had that happen for any of the other RDBS (this is my first time using sqlite) so I didn't really think about that as an issue.
Thanks Marc.